# What does the RSA key fingerprint represent for a forwarded port?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

My understanding of a RSA fingerprint is that it basically is a hash a key.

My understanding of a forwarded port is per the following section of `man ssh`:

```
 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to
         be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.  This
         works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the remote
         side, and whenever a connection is made to this port, the connec‐
         tion is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is
         made to host port hostport from the local machine.
```

When using ssh to connect to a forwarded port, what is the RSA key fingerprint a hash of?  [Using identical RSA authentication keys on multiple machines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367938/using-identical-rsa-authentication-keys-on-multiple-machines) will describe why I am asking.

Or through example, what are the two fingerprints below actually of?

1. RSA key fingerprint is 94:21:d2:fc:70:2d:8d:bb:71:30:0f:4d:52:49:01:43.
2. RSA key fingerprint is b2:5b:19:25:91:50:3c:45:73:c7:7e:4f:da:c3:f6:f3.

## Getting first fingerprint

Machine 1

```
sshtunnel@pi_one:~ $ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 sshtunnel@192.168.1.10
```

Common Machine

```
[sshtunnel@devserver ~]$ ssh -p 2222 sshtunnel@localhost
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2222 ([::1]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 94:21:d2:fc:70:2d:8d:bb:71:30:0f:4d:52:49:01:43.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
```

## Getting second fingerprint

Machine 2

```
sshtunnel@pi_two:~ $ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 sshtunnel@192.168.1.10
```

Common Machine

```
[sshtunnel@devserver ~]$ ssh -p 2222 sshtunnel@localhost
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2222 ([::1]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b2:5b:19:25:91:50:3c:45:73:c7:7e:4f:da:c3:f6:f3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
[sshtunnel@devserver ~]$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host's public keys in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub`:

```
$ ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 60:6e:7a:10:85:a4:14:f1:37:44:88:17:29:67:b1:e1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ^C

$ ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
256 60:6e:7a:10:85:a4:14:f1:37:44:88:17:29:67:b1:e1 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub (ECDSA)
```

(Note that it doesn't matter if you ask `ssh-keygen` for a fingerprint of the private key (without the `.pub` extension), it automatically reads the corresponding public key instead.)

In your case, it's the RSA key that is mentioned, so `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`, and with the port forwarding, it's the host `ssh` eventually connects to.

With newer versions of `ssh-keygen`, the default output is the base64-encoded SHA256 hash of the key. Adding the `-E md5` option gives the hex-encoded MD5 hash (but note that now there's a prefix indicating the hash type):

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
256 SHA256:4+dfNAIjGq72HL9UeNEpne8J54yj/4wFpi+/4Bv7dhQ root@... (ECDSA)
$ ssh-keygen -Emd5 -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
256 MD5:3c:18:e7:9c:ee:e8:6a:38:7d:74:ef:2f:a5:51:ee:1a root@... (ECDSA)
```

Comment: `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` proves you are correct.  Thank you!  Makes sense now.  A given user for a given host must be the same entity.

Comment: Where is the private key located which is associated with `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`?

Comment: @user1032531, `ssh_host_rsa_key` is the private key `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` is the corresponding public key.

Comment: So how do I get the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` to produce a fingerprint in the same format as the ssh warning message, like `60:6e:7a:10:85:a4:14:f1:37:44:88:17:29:67:b1:e1`? The `ssh-keygen -lf` command just gives me SHA256 hash format. Thanks.

Comment: @bitofagoob, `ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` ([manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html)). The older versions that don't support `-E` always give the MD5 hash (as in the answer), newer ones default to the SHA256 hash and prefix either one with the type (unlike the old version).